# Do questions need to have the distro in the title if they are tagged appropriately?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example:

[image]

You can see that Debian is in the title, but the [debian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) tag is shown directly after. This to me seems a bit redundant. In the same way that you wouldn't put `Java` in the title of a question on StackOverflow.

Should we remove the distro name from the titles and just use tags to identify them?

Answer (score 6):

Going on the `do not repeat yourself` principle, I say yes (get rid of them).

Obviously in your image, the [debian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) is repeated, so what's the point in having it in the title? The title should give details about the question, not say what OS you're using or whatever.

Also, SE gives one of the tags before the question name in the title of the page (as in title that appears in the browser bar, title you set like `<title></title>` in html). On the question you link [boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot) is appearing in the title,  (for me), like this:

> boot - Auto-start X-windows / gdm on the standard Debian build - Raspberry Pi Beta - Stack Exchange.

Comment: Who looks at the title of the webpage? To me, tags in the post title seem redundant. I'll edit my question to show more clearly.

Comment: @Jivi, I do. Oh, I see what you mean thanks to the image.